# Как из TXT-файла записать данные в CSV-таблицу?

Tags: python, csv

У меня есть данные, которые находятся в текстовом документе - это ссылки(скрин 1)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу каждую ссылку засунуть в отдельный столбик в CSV-таблицу, используя Python

Есть такой код:

```
file = open("Date.txt")
i = 0

with open('data.csv', 'w') as csvF:
    writer = csv.writer(csvF)

    while i < 10:
        href = file.readline()
        writer.writerow(href)
        i = i + 1
```

Но он вставляет в столбик не ссылку, а буквы, состоящих из ссылок (скрин2)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите начинающему Phyton'исту решить проблему. Надеюсь разъяснил всё понятно

Answer (score 1):

Метод [`writerow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) принимает не одно, а множество значений, которые должны быть записаны в строку. То есть он будет воспринимать `href` как итерируемый объект, каждый элемент которого должен быть помещён в новый столбец.

Поместите `href` в список, и тогда ссылка будет помещена в первый столбец:

```py
writer.writerow([href])
```

---

Чтобы после ссылки не вставлялся перевод строки, заранее удалите его:

```py
href = file.readline().rstrip()
```

А чтобы не было пустых строк между ссылками, [укажите параметр `newline`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#id3):

```
open('data.csv', 'w', newline='')
```

Comment: Cпасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Всё решил, проблема была в коде

Вот готовый вариант:

```
file = open("Date.txt")
i = 0
with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvF:
    writer = csv.writer(csvF, delimiter=";")
    while i < 10:
        href = file.readline()
        writer.writerow([href])
        print(href)
        i = i + 1
```